# Set logger level to Debug for specific action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have strange error which happens time to time, so to figure out I need more information in the log file. 
But I don't want to use Debug level for whole application, only for one controller action.

I'm using Rails 3.2.14, but don't want to use Rails.logger.silence(...) because it will be removed in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible with `Rails.logger.level`.

```
def some_controller_action
  old_log_level = Rails.logger.level
  Rails.logger.level = :debug

  # Lots of code that needs to be logged

  Rails.logger.level = old_log_level
end
```